# What does this header means in php

Tags: cookies, curl, header

After using curl to get source code of a url I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Content-Length: 7036 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727 Set-Cookie:
```

And then I get the source code, but not like the source that I see if I open the page with my browser and look at the source code.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the http header response from the server you are requesting the page from, its a 200 OK which just means that everything went correctly.

The reason you're seeing this along with the source code is you have the curl option CURLOPT_HEADER set to true, set it to false and you will not see the header output any more.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

PHP Manual Reference:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Ok, thanks.
Why then I don't get the full source page as I see it when I open the url with a browser?

Comment: Well that depends on what exactly you're doing, are you doing this in a browser, command line? Are you outputting anything else while doing this? It seems to me like there might be something impeding the browser's ability to render the html that you're pulling. Tell me more context and i can perhaps offer a better answer, actually show me specifically what you're doing and i can help the best.

Comment: Thats my code:

    function curl_download($Url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;

I am not getting the same source code as I get when I open the url with the browser.

Comment: One note, perhaps use a pastebin for code in answer comments. Anyway, from your code there doesnt seem to be anything wrong, i'm assuming its something outside the function itself. If you simply echo the returned string from the function without any other output it should render correctly in the browser. Are you using any other code in the script that uses this function? If so thats probably it, check what else you've output and check any includes as well. It also may be a php notice or warning thats mucking it up. Is this live on a server at all i can see?

Comment: I am using wamp, it's on my computer.
I echoed the output(just it) I do get a source code.
The problem is that its a bad source code, like the url I'm trying to get it's source knows that I am not a browser and it gives me a bad source code.

Comment: I see, you are getting an alternative source code to the source code your expect to see? I understand now. Its highly likely to be your user-agent string then, its currently set to IE5 which is extremely old and perhaps triggering a page on the site saying the browser isnt supported, perhaps change the $agent variable to a more up to date user string, for instance, this is mine: Mozilla/5.0 (Ubuntu; X11; Linux i686; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0

Comment: I'm afraid i'm out of ideas then, there must be something that is different between your script and the page in the browser, if its not user agent detection, perhaps its a cookie or something? What is the page you're trying to grab?

Comment: fileflyer.com
I think it's a cookie check, I'm trying to disable my cookies now and we will see

Comment: Ok, I just blocked my cookies, and still it worked in the browser.
I really don't know what else it can be..no cookies no agent..